# Where is this space being created and how to fix?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to figure out why my slider div is not running flush with my header div. it is being pushed down 20px and i have no idea why. I have looked at my chrome developer tools and see nothign to make it  be pushed down 20px. please nay help would be great.
 here is my jsdFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Lparspfn/

HTML

```
<div id="body-container">
    <div class="base">
        <header>
            <div class="top-nav">
                <p>Participant Login</p>
                <p>Plan Sponsorship Login</p>
                <p>RIA Login</p>
            </div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
              </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="slider-wrapper"></div>
    </div><!-- End of base container -->
</div><!-- End of body-container wrapper -->
```

Comment: are you referring to the blue bar? because that's caused by the margin-bottom on your .navbar

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lparspfn/1/

Comment: Use a browser with decent developer tools. You can then usually inspect every part of the page, with the appropriate css for that area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap, the navbar class has a 20px bottom margin. In the source:

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, wonder why it doesnt show up on the inspector tool in chrome?

Comment: It does for me, that's how I found it.

Comment: Your right it does show up, i skipped over it some how. thank you